# my redux state changed but the view don't

Tags: redux, react-redux

I'm building a game called would you rather,
the game allows user to pick from usernames as a fake login,

everything is working well with my game
but when the user answers a question the state changes but the view don't rerender
I think this is because of mutation but I can't find my mistake so here is my code

questions.js reducer

```
        case ADD_ANSWER:
            const {qid,answer,authedUser} = action.payload
            return {
                ...state,
                [qid]:{
                    ...state[qid],
                    [answer]:{
                        ...state[qid][answer],
                        votes:[...state[qid][answer].votes, authedUser]
                    }
                }
            }
```

users.js reducer

```
        case ADD_USER_ANSWER:
            const {qid,authedUser,answer} = action.payload
            return{
                ...state,
                [authedUser]:{
                    ...state[authedUser],
                    answers:{
                    ...state[authedUser].answers,
                    [qid]:answer
                },
              },
            }
```

I call these two actions in one function using redux-thunk

shared.js

```
export const handleAddAnswer = ({authedUser,qid,answer})=>{
    return (dispatch)=>{
                _saveQuestionAnswer ({ authedUser, qid, answer }).then(()=>{
                    dispatch(addAnswer({authedUser,qid,answer}))
                    dispatch(addUserAnswer({authedUser,qid,answer}))
        })
    }

}
```

then finally I use it in my component using mapStateToProps
Home.js component

```
function mapStateToProps({questions,authedUser,users}){
    return {
        questions,
        unanswered:Object.values(questions).filter((question)=>{
            if(!Object.keys(authedUser.answers).includes(question.id)){
                return question
            }
        }).sort((a,b)=>b.timestamp - a.timestamp),
        answered:Object.values(questions).filter((question)=>{
            if(Object.keys(authedUser.answers).includes(question.id)){
                return question
            }
        }).sort((a,b)=>b.timestamp - a.timestamp),
        users,
        authedUser,
    }
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Home)
```

Comment: There is no mutation going on here. How does your component subscribe to that?

Comment: I edited the question to add more information

Comment: I'm stuck in this for like 2 days so could anybody please help?

Comment: Since your selectors there return new objects on every single execution, that component should fully rerender on every dispatch, no matter if the action changed the store or not.

Can you see the state change in the devtools?